# VLOOKUP specific cells in one column conditional on blanks in another

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to add vlookup formulas to multiple columns (E:I) when the corresponding cell in column "D" is blank. For example when cell D113 and down are blank, I want to add "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet4!$A:$L,5,False)" to cells E113:and down and then repeat for colums G,H,I,etc.

But the code I have now as shown below adds the vlookup to all cells in column E & lastrow, overwriting existing data above E113. Code is as follows:

```
Sub PrevInactives()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lastrow)
Select Case Cell.Value
    Case ""
    If Cell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
    Range("E2:E" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!$A:$L,5,FALSE)"
    End If
End Select

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Does anyone have a solution for my dilemma?

Thanks,

Jason

EDIT, 9/26/17: Below is the updated code I added in, but when I run this macro, nothing happens.

```
Sub PrevInactives()
Dim r As Long
For r = 2 To lastrow
    lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 4).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(r - 1, 4).Value) Then
        Range(Cells(r, 5), Cells(r, 9)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2" & r & ",Sheet4!$A:$L,False)"
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to have inside of your loop something such as:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(r,4).Value) AND Not IsEmpty(Cells(r-1,4).Value) Then
    'Insert vlookup stuffs
End If
```

Rather than using For Each as the loop, you can loop For r = 2 to LR using the above example:

```
Dim r as Long
For r = 2 to lastrow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(r,4).Value) AND Not IsEmpty(Cells(r-1,4).Value) Then
        Range(Cells(r,5),Cells(r,9)).Formula= "=VLOOKUP($A" & r & ",Sheet3!$A:$L,5,FALSE)"
    End If
Next r
```

---

Essentially, the issue is that you are using:

```
Range("E2:E" & lastrow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!$A:$L,5,FALSE)"
```

When you want Cell.Formula = ""; you are adding the formula to all of those cells if the case is ever true.

---

**Edit, 20170926:**

Fixing your code:

```
Sub PrevInactives()
    Dim r As Long, lastrow as Long
    lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'Need to define before looping
    'You could use lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    For r = 2 To lastrow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 4).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(r - 1, 4).Value) Then
            Range(Cells(r, 5), Cells(r, 9)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A" & r & ",Sheet4!$A:$L,False)" 'You had in A2&r, so it would be A22, A23, ..., A2&LR
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Where the range of cells exists for adding the formula, you can have the ending range be Cells(lastrow,9) if you want to add that formula to all the cells, rather than keep looping through D for blanks.  Also, i added a $ before the A2 in the vlookup.

Comment: Thanks Cyril,  I put that code in, but nothing happens when I run the macro. Am I missing a few lines of code?

Comment: @JCas Can you post your code that you've now input, appending it to your post?  I'd have to see what you put in to make more sense of the issue.

Comment: See above. Thanks.

Comment: @JCas See my edit.  Hopefully this fixes the issue.  Make sure to step-through with F8 on the first loop so you can verify that the desired actions are being performed.